# Does the Azure REST API have a call similar to AWS's GetCallerIdentity?

Tags: azure

I'm writing an integration where I have an OAuth token and need to determine what AAD account it belongs to.  What endpoint do I call to return information about the current caller, similar to AWS's [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remember that OAuth token is simply JWT token. This means it's just base64 encoded JSON. If you decode it you can get info about caller without need to call external systems.

[image]

Inside of the token there will be appid (application id of app which generated the token) and oid (object id) which also gives you ID which can be used.

You can use https://jwt.io website to parse token and see details.

```
  "aud": "https://management.core.windows.net/",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/1f342340-9423-4dce-ac05-7f195c4ee405/",
  "iat": 1568320436,
  "nbf": 1568320436,
  "exp": 1568324336,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "AUQAu/8MAAAAqrqxt74MBbBmBr+rc3453443IB5NNBSdw67r9k47ipKFs1UTI+E9+73juIUtGDsI9U2Iw==",
  "altsecid": "5::10037543E4F4D8",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "appid": "04b07795-83db-4231-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "email": "adam@marczak.io",
  "groups": [
    "317bace5-2654-468e-826c-dc65cdfd2665"
  ],
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/dda56080-1234-534-9fd5-a88f5833ea9a/",
  "ipaddr": "89.xx.xx.xx",
  "name": "Adam Marczak",
  "oid": "3eb1f86e-bfe8-4909-adb9-f523454af378",
  "puid": "1003205540D15DFB",
  "pwd_exp": "153322",
  "pwd_url": "https://portal.microsoftonline.com/ChangePassword.aspx",
  "scp": "user_impersonation",
  "sub": "uvJcE-2Sjt19d5m1111111yP68CDdPf4eK84",
  "tid": "1f0fb2d0-9423-1111-ac05-7f195c4ee405",
  "unique_name": "adam@marczak.io",
  "uti": "6oskpTokwBVkrAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "62e90394-69f5-4211-9110-012177145e10"
  ]
}
```

If you need more info about caller ID you can use Microsoft Graph to get caller info like.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/me
```

or

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/users/<id_from_token>
```